# understanding BTree capacity

Tags: java

What I've understood aboutt BTrees is :

> - if root BTree size is 32, the level 1 have 1024 keys capacity
> - the level 2 can sort 1048576  keys
> - the real capacity is 512 for level 1 and 524288 on Level 2, because leaves are half filled.

Am'I Ok or clearly out of concern?

Comment: why is this tagged "java"?

Comment: I'm working with Java's database db4objects (http://db4o.com/), and I not certain than algorithm is a good flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula to compute a Btree's capacity: Assuming the maximum number of children is D, maximum number of keys for any node is D-1. Level 1 (the root level) always has one node with D-1 keys. Level 2 at most can have D nodes, each of those nodes can have at most D-1 keys, So level 2 has D*(D-1) keys. Level 3 can have at most D^2 Children (because any node in level 2 can have D children and there are at most D nodes in level 2). Each of these nodes in level 3 can have at  most D-1 keys, Thus the number of keys in level 3 is D^2 * (D-1), and so on ... for any level i, the maximum number of keys is D^(i-1) *(D-1). Thus the capacity of the tree is obtained by summing up the capacity of each level.